# Trouble getting the top N reoccuring values out of a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Hello so I am having a problem with some of my python. I am trying to make a program to take in a csv file and tell me the 50 highest appearing words in a column. 
my csv file follows this format:
ID, City, State, Hotel Name, Price
1, Atlanta, GA, Le Royale, 200

I want for instance to go through this list and tell me the 50 most common cities.
My code:

```
def count_amount(fin_name):
    with open(fin_name, 'rb') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    next(reader)
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for row in sortedlist:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4])
        if row[1]  != 'City':
            d[row[1]].append(float(row[3]))
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        c = Counter(k)
        print c.most_common(50)
```

I'm sure that my problem is coming from my c = Counter(k), it prints the individual letters of each city name instead of the city itself. So it will print (('a', 2), ('d', 1), ('k', 1), ('l', 1), ('O', 1), ('n', 1) instead of telling me how many times 'Oakland' shows up in my csv file. How do I get it to show me the entire string?
(note: I am aware of the indentation I am just terrible at entering my code into stack overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pandas` is a viable option, this is straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file
df = pd.read_csv(fin_name)

# return value counts as {city -> count} dictionary
d = df['City'].value_counts().to_dict()

# sort descending, return top 50 most common as list of tuples
d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:50]
```

Comment: Its, if I use pandas do I no longer need the csv library?

Comment: Incredible, thanks! Out of curiosity, was there no way to solve it using the 'collections' library?

Comment: There is, but it would take longer to code! From an academic perspective, it's good to learn it once, but then trust tried & tested libraries.

Comment: I hope I'm not late asking but how would I solve using just Counter? My program works just fine but when I try to tweak it to exclude pandas, I can't get past just characters instead of the entire string for my Counter output. Thanks